# Can't resolve 'SimpleSlider.js' from "react-slick"

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm having a hard time understanding what's happening here. I'm installing the "react-slick" component and I followed the github's instruction but there seems to be something going wrong (The slider is not found) Could you please help me with this? Here's the relevant parts:

Where it's called:
[image]

Where it's rendered:
[image]

My package.json file:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of linking to a jpg of the code/result/config, please add it as text/code, so it is easier to search and copy when answering.
Also, copying the exact/full error message you got, will help.

Comment: Thanks - i'm starting with stackoverflow. Gonna edit the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your

```
import {SimpleSlider} from "SimpleSlider.js"
```

to use exported default and relative path:

```
import SimpleSlider from "./SimpleSlider.js"
```

If not that, please post the exact error message

Comment: That was it. THANKS!